# What does だからここでもただ先生と書くだけで本名は打ち明けない mean exactly?

Tags: translation, meaning, word-choice, nuances

> だからここでもただ先生と書くだけで本名は打ち明けない。

From my own comprehension, it literally means ...

> That's why, even here, I only write sensei. His real name is not revealed/confided.

Have I interpreted it correctly?

Comment: Welcome to JLSE!  Just so you know, we do not function as a bulk translation service.  We will be better able to help you if you include your thought process through the translation.  That way we can zero in on areas of misunderstanding.  See: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/22352

Comment: I think it's enough effort if OP has already provided their translation (which doesn't seem a machine translation), though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> だからここでもただ先生と書くだけで本名は打ち明けない。
>   That's why, even here, I only write sensei. His real name is not revealed/confided.

I think you're on the right track.

To break it down to smaller chunks...

だから -- So,
ここでも -- here too; here (in this book) as well
ただ～だけ -- only; just
先生と書く -- I write (his name as) sensei; I refer to him as sensei
で -- the continuative form of the copula だ
本名は打ち明けない -- I won't reveal his real name

Put together, it would literally be like...

"So, here (in this book) as well, I will just write his name as sensei / refer to him as sensei, and won't reveal his real name."